# How do I turn off overwrite warning for JavaFX FileChooser when appending to a file?

Tags: java, io, append, javafx-8, filechooser

I need to create a data-entry JavaFx class which outputs to a file in append mode. In the simplified runnable example below (imports deleted), I can create a file, put in initial data, and then append to it with no problem. However, if I close the program and run it again later, the FileChooser will help find the file, but warns:
"Confirm Save As __
TryFile.txt already exists. __
Do you want to replace it?".

If I choose to confirm, the new data is appended as intended and the file is not replaced. 
How do I turn off that warning? I am using Java 8_20 on Windows 7.

Note: I have corrected the code as per suggestions below. See AppendToFile().

```
public class TryAppend extends Application
{
  static File file;

  static void initiatefile( String setupInfo )
  {
    FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
    choose.getExtensionFilters().add(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "Text doc(*.txt)", "*.txt" ) );
    choose.setInitialFileName( "*.txt" );
    choose.setInitialDirectory( new File(System.getProperty("user.home") ) );
    file = choose.showSaveDialog( null );
    if ( file != null )
    {
        if ( file.getName().endsWith( ".txt" ) )
        {
           try( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( file )))) 
           {
               out.println( setupInfo );
           }catch (IOException e) {
               System.err.println(e);
           }
        }
    }
  }

  static void appendToFile( String appendString )
  {
    if (file == null)
    {
        FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
        choose.getExtensionFilters().add(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( "Text doc(*.txt)", "*.txt" ) );
        choose.setInitialDirectory( new File(System.getProperty("user.home") ) );
        file = choose.showOpenDialog( null ); //Now corrected. Previously 
                                              //was: choose.showSaveDialog( null );                    
    }

    if ( file != null )
    {   

        try( PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( file, true )))) 
        {
            out.println( appendString );
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
  { 
     primaryStage.setTitle( "Try Append to File" ); 
     Group root = new Group(); 
     Scene scene = new Scene( root, 300, 200 ); 
     Button initBtn = new Button(); 
     initBtn.setLayoutX( 100 ); 
     initBtn.setLayoutY( 40 ); 
     initBtn.setText( "Initiate File" ); 
     initBtn.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
     { 
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
        { 
            initiatefile( "Initial data" ); 
        } 
     } ); 
     Button appendBtn = new Button(); 
     appendBtn.setLayoutX( 90 ); 
     appendBtn.setLayoutY( 100 ); 
     appendBtn.setText( "Append to File" ); 
     appendBtn.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() 
     { 
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
        { 
            appendToFile( "Appended data" );
        } 
     } ); 
     root.getChildren().add( initBtn ); 
     root.getChildren().add( appendBtn ); 
     primaryStage.setScene( scene ); 
     primaryStage.show(); 
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does seem like one could regard "choose a file to append to" as an open function, even though the application will be writing to the file.

Comment: Yes! I fixed it as suggested in appendToFile() by replacing file = choose.showSaveDialog( null ); with file = choose.showOpenDialog( null ); Works great. Thanks!

Comment: I corrected the code in the original post, in case anyone is learning JavaFx FileChooser and wants to try the features I used.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately peeking at the operation of `QuantemToolkit.showFileChooser()`, it eventually delegates to a _native_ method `Application._showFileChooser()`. Reading up to the native call I dont see any of that code doing any kind of loop that could be responsible for the 'are you sure you want to overwrite?' So to actually make this happen is going to require a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

The **Save As** dialog cannot do this because prompting to overwrite is hard-coded as `TRUE` in the [GTK source file](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/bca1bfc5e3b04293c13417fd923d99864cdd9147/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/native-glass/gtk/GlassCommonDialogs.cpp#L125):

```c
gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (chooser), TRUE);
```

[JDK-8299969](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8299969) was logged against this issue, and will need to be resolved before the overwrite prompt can be ignored.

Using the **Open** dialog is a workaround, although it has drawbacks.

For [KeenWrite](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite), I opted to have a hot-key that bypasses the **Save As** dialog altogether by repeating the previous export action. This can be accomplished by creating a `javafx.concurrent.Service` that is able to re-run a `javafx.concurrent.Task`, such as:

```java
final var service = new Service<Path>() {
  @Override
  protected Task<Path> createTask() {
    final var task = new Task<Path>() {
      @Override
      protected Path call() throws Exception {
        // Do the work that Save As would do.
      }
    };

    // Handle the success functionality.
    task.setOnSucceeded( this::successs );

    // Handle the failure functionality.
    task.setOnFailed( this::failure );

    return task;
  }
};
```

In this way, if **Save As** is a feature users may do quite often, it can be replaced with a "silent" version that doesn't prompt with any dialogs. Except for the first time, which creates the initial action that will be re-run for subsequent "silent" executions.